# PlayHt integration with NextJs

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, next.js13

I've been trying to integrate play.ht node module with nextjs.
My goal is to create an api endpoint in nextjs14 that will receive an text in body and using playht, will convert the text to audio and send it as a response to play it in the frontend.
Importing the package give the following error  `⨯ Error: Cannot find module 'tls'`

Can someone guide with the node module usage?